# Why do I need ntfs-3g when I have already enabled NTFS support in the kernel?

Tags: kernel, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-3g

When configuring the kernel I see an option to add read-write support for NTFS. Then when mounting my NTFS partition I still have to install ntfs-3g and pass ntfs-3g as the type. I thought if I add NTFS support in the kernel then I wouldn't have to install a library for it. Why is it so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kernel driver is still read only and has no full write support yet, only with many restrictions.

Comment: As http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/Documentation/filesystems/ntfs.txt states, the biggest limitation is that creating or removing files/directories is not supported.

Comment: so that flag `CONFIG_NTFS_RW` is just a placeholder?

Comment: No, the ntfs driver has write support, but only limited. See the ntfs.txt file.